# MvcSiteMapNode does not working using asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#-4.0

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" changeFrequency="Always" updatePriority="Normal">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Search Results" controller="Home" action="Search"/>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Filter (City)" controller="Home" action="SearchByCity"/>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Filter (Type/Cat)" controller="Home" action="SearchByCatType"/>

  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" controller="Props" action="Details">
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
   <mvcSiteMapNode title="Login" controller="Account" action="Login">  <!--Account--> 

          <mvcSiteMapNode title="Dashboard" controller="Agent" action="Index">                
           <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" controller="Agent" action="Details"/>                
          </mvcSiteMapNode>

          <mvcSiteMapNode title="Dashboard" controller="propOwn" action="Index">
            <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" controller="propOwn" action="Details"/>
          </mvcSiteMapNode>

    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Log out" controller="Account" action="LogOff"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Reset Password" controller="Account" action="ForgotPass"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Regesteration" controller="Account" action="Register"/>
    </mvcSiteMapNode> <!-- /Account -->
```

Details nodes are not working  in breadcrumbs under all nodes. Adice will be appreciated